# How to set values using jquery in the form below json

Tags: jquery

I have a form generator  with  json data

```
{ "10" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Sublimacja",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field7",
      "type" : "dropdown",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "Sublimacja 205g"
    },
  "11" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Druk+UV",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field8",
      "type" : "dropdown",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "Kalka"
    },
  "12" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Rodzaj+wyko%C5%84czenia",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field9",
      "type" : "dropdown",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "Cięcie do wymiaru"
    },
  "13" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Rodzaj+wysy%C5%82ki",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field10",
      "type" : "dropdown",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "UPS Standard"
    },
  "14" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Adres+wysy%C5%82ki",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field11",
      "type" : "para",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "15" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Uwagi+dodatkowe",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field12",
      "type" : "para",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "16" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "divider",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : "divider",
      "validation" : "divider",
      "value" : "Plik 1"
    },
  "17" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+pliku+1",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field14",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "18" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Ilo%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field15",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "19" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Wysoko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field16",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "2" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : null,
      "validation" : null,
      "value" : ""
    },
  "20" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Szeroko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field17",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "21" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "divider",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : "divider",
      "validation" : "divider",
      "value" : "Plik 2"
    },
  "22" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+Pliku+2",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field19",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "23" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Ilo%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field20",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "24" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Szeroko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field21",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "25" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Wysoko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field22",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "26" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "divider",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : "divider",
      "validation" : "divider",
      "value" : "Plik 3"
    },
  "27" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+Pliku+3",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field24",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "28" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Ilo%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field25",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "29" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Szeroko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field26",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "3" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+Firmy",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "1",
      "tooltip" : "field0",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "fdfdf"
    },
  "30" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Wysoko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field27",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "31" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "divider",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : "divider",
      "validation" : "divider",
      "value" : "Plik 4"
    },
  "32" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+Pliku+4",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field29",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "33" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Ilo%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field30",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "34" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Szeroko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field31",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "35" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Wysoko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field32",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "36" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "divider",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : "divider",
      "validation" : "divider",
      "value" : "Plik 5"
    },
  "37" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwa+Pliku+5",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field34",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "38" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Ilo%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field35",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "39" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Szeroko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field36",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "4" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "NIP",
      "max" : "10",
      "min" : "10",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field1",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "integers",
      "value" : "1234567890"
    },
  "40" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Wysoko%C5%9B%C4%87",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field37",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    },
  "41" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Plik",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field38",
      "type" : "upload",
      "validation" : "file",
      "value" : "0"
    },
  "42" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "title",
      "max" : null,
      "min" : null,
      "required" : null,
      "tooltip" : null,
      "type" : null,
      "validation" : null,
      "value" : "Zamówienie"
    },
  "5" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Imi%C4%99",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "1",
      "tooltip" : "field2",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "dfdf"
    },
  "6" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Nazwisko",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "1",
      "tooltip" : "field3",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "dfdff"
    },
  "7" : { "custom" : "autoreply",
      "custom2" : "replyto",
      "label" : "Email",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "1",
      "tooltip" : "field4",
      "type" : "email",
      "validation" : "email",
      "value" : "kasper@dolczewski.eu"
    },
  "8" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Rodzaj+zam%C3%B3wienia",
      "max" : "",
      "min" : "",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field5",
      "type" : "dropdown",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : "Druk sublimacyjny transferowy"
    },
  "9" : { "custom" : null,
      "custom2" : null,
      "label" : "Inne",
      "max" : "60",
      "min" : "0",
      "required" : "0",
      "tooltip" : "field6",
      "type" : "text",
      "validation" : "",
      "value" : ""
    }
}
```

And a form which has input files with name

```
<input type="text" name="Nazwa Firmy_text__1_0_60_field0" ng-style="{width: el.wid}" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="inst ng-binding" ng-style="{ fontSize: con[0].ifs+"px", color: con[0].ifc }" style=""></span>
```

What is the easiest way to set the values to the form using jquery or maybe some plugin because the name of each field is generated dynamically based on inputted json data so sometimes it can be name_fieldtyoe_max_min sometimes without min and max

Is there a way to check a bit of the name of the field compare it to json data and then set the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to set a value of input field if you know only partial name

```
$('input[name^="name_fieldtyoe"]').val('This is value');
```

The above line will set value for input field that has name staring with `name_fieldtyoe`.

See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information

Comment: `function populate(frm, data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);
  });
}` i found such function to populate form directly from json . Is this possible to use this above selectors to find matching part of name in form and in json and then set the value or it is better to take json data to php arrays and then operate on this in jquery

Comment: Yes it is possible. Instead of `$('name='+key+']')` , you can use any of the wildcard selectors i.e. if you want to match starting of name with key in your JSON, you can write `$('name^='+key+']')`